# maven-release-plugin [ERROR] fatal: pathspec '' did not match any files

Tags: java, git, maven, maven-release-plugin

I'm trying to do a release of my OSS library, but I keep running in to a strange issue with the maven-release-plugin. This used to work fine. I've probably updated either Maven or Git but I can't seem to find the right combination to get things working again for the release.

Has anyone run into this issue, and does anyone know of a solution? I'm using the Maven Shade Plugin (which is what is creating the dependency-reduced-pom.xml files in the build.)

```
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 09:27 min
[INFO] Finished at: 2015-11-04T08:23:07-05:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 111M/1039M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-release-plugin:2.5.1:prepare (default-cli) on project rewrite-parent: Unable to commit files
[ERROR] Provider message:
[ERROR] The git-add command failed.
[ERROR] Command output:
[ERROR] fatal: pathspec 'config-prettyfaces/dependency-reduced-pom.xml' did not match any files
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
```

The dependency-reduced-pom.xml, as I understand it, is a temporary file used while merging dependencies into an uber-jar, and should not be committed, so I'm confused why maven is trying to add this file at all.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Do you want the `dependency-reduced-pom.xml` file? It is possible to not create this file.

Comment: I don't want the file, per-say. I just need the pom to be reduced to omit dependencies that were shaded in.

Comment: I've tried updating to release plugin 2.5.3 and shade plugin 2.4.2 with no success. I've tried relocating the dep reduced pom to target/ with no success. It simply produces an error about target/ being in the .gitignore file.

Comment: Question is, what do you want? Do you want the `maven-shade-plugin` not to create this file or do you want to generate it but then ignore it on release?

Comment: I want it to generate it and do its job normally, then ignore it on release. It should not be attempting to commit this file. The file is temporary and should never be committed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out, at least a workaround:

Using 'checkModificationExcludes" configuration option of the maven-release-plugin to exclude the dependency-reduced-pom.xml seems to work around the issue, though I'm not sure this is exactly what the property was intended for (the documentation is unclear):

```
 <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.5.3</version>
    <configuration>
       <checkModificationExcludes>
          <checkModificationExclude>dependency-reduced-pom.xml</checkModificationExclude>
       </checkModificationExcludes>
    </configuration>
 </plugin>
```